# Powershell - check exchange db's status

Tags: powershell

I am new with powershell and I wrote this script to check the db's status:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn

$null = Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus |  Where-Object {$_.status -match "Mounted" } -outvariable dbstatus
$null = $dbstatus.status

if (-not $dbstatus.status -eq "Mounted"){
Write-Host "OK"
}

Else {Write-Host $dbstatus.name  status: $dbstatus.status}
```

It's working well. The only problem is if I have more than 1 db unmounted, I'm getting something like this:

```
db1 db2 status: Unmounted Unmounted
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$dbstatus` is a *collection* of `DatabaseCopyStatusEntry` objects, you'll want to iterate over it in a loop to get the status of each individual DB:

```
foreach($db in $dbstatus){
    if ($db.Status -eq "Mounted"){
        Write-Host $db.Name "OK"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host $db.Name status: $db.Status
    }
}
```